# Architecture to process large number of items in .Net

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, parallel-processing

I need to make a service that constantly checks the database (SQL Server) for items or message to be processed.

The problem is that sometimes it needs to process or send a large number of this items (from 30000 to 1000000) at a time as soon as possible since probably a new load would arrive soon to be processed too.

The process doesn't have to send them all at the sime time, each item is independent from the others, but it needs to process them as fast as possible and without hanging up.

Can U suggest me an architecture, model, pattern, sample or something similar to accomplish this in .Net, including the part of reading all this huge amount of records from the database but the most important part is to process the items in a efficient and robust way.

Would be nice (but not necessary) that the suggested solution could be scaled up to be executed in several machines at the same time to do some load balancing if needed.

Thanks

Comment: why a database, specifically? it *sounds* like you are actually implementing a work queue here; there are lots of products (many free) that would excel at this

Comment: Use a [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) which streams the data record for record.

Comment: @Tim that sounds a lot like suggesting a specific *type* of hammer to use to drive screws

Comment: @MarcGravell: That's at least the most obvious approach if i want to get many records and if all are independend from each other. OP should tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Tim well, for starters when you start talking (as the OP does) about multiple workers, you need to start thinking about scrolling atomic dequeues so that nothing is duplicated; this would come for free from any system designed as a queue store. Heck, a redis list would suffice and be far simpler and more appropriate than a database

Comment: @Mark It needs to read a database since this records could be inserted a long time ago an need to processed scheduled at a specific date and time. The least important problem is to read them from the database, the most important part is to process the items  in a efficient and robust way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Can U suggest me a work queue product to check it out if this is what I need?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am going to bet beat up on this but.

Reading 30,000 to 1,000,000 records is pretty fast.
So I suspect processing them is the bottle neck.

A dirty approach is to take a table lock in a transaction and read out like 1000 or 10,000 at a time and mark them as inProcess.
Read them into a List using a DataReader so you can release the lock ASAP.

Process the list.

If you need to validate they are process then mark them as such.
Use a transactionID so you can update them with a single statement.
Every once in a while check for inProcess items that did not clear.

Get the next set.

Not pretty, not the most efficient, but is scales easily.

Consider parallel for the processing so you scale within a machine.